# Почему код работает не корректно?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Всем привет, на сайте Wordpress c Woocommerce добавил код в файл functions.php,
по задумке:
Этот код должен добавить новые поля в админке, в каждой карточке товара, при заполнении показывать их на сайте в соответствующей карточке, а если поле не заполнено, то и показывать не надо.
Что получилось в итоге:
Поля есть, заполняются и отражаются как надо, но если поле очистить, то при сохранении он подставляет обратно все что было вписано.
Вот такой код:

```html
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'art_woo_add_custom_fields' );
function art_woo_add_custom_fields() {
   global $product, $post;
   echo '<div class="options_group">';// Группировка полей
   // текстовое поле
   woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
      'id'                => '_text_field',
      'label'             => __( 'Текстовое поле', 'woocommerce' ),
      'placeholder'       => 'Текстовое поле',
   ) );
   // Тектовая область
   woocommerce_wp_textarea_input( array(
      'id'            => '_textarea', // Идентификатор поля
      'label'         => 'Область текста', // Заголовок поля
      'placeholder'   => 'Ввод текста', // Надпись внутри поля
      'class'         => 'textarea-field', // Произвольный класс поля
      'wrapper_class' => 'wrap-textarea', // Класс обертки поля
      'name'          => 'textarea-field', // Имя поля
   ) );
echo '</div>';
}
/*****************/
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'art_woo_custom_fields_save', 10 );
function art_woo_custom_fields_save( $post_id ) {
// Text Field
  $woocommerce_text_field = $_POST['_text_field'];
  if( !empty( $woocommerce_text_field ) )
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_text_field', esc_attr( $woocommerce_text_field ) );
// Textarea
  $woocommerce_textarea = $_POST['_textarea-field'];
  if( !empty( $woocommerce_textarea ) )
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_textarea', esc_html( $woocommerce_textarea ) );
   // Сохранение произвольного поля по выбору товаров с поиском
   if (  isset( $_POST['product_field_type'] ) && !empty($_POST['product_field_type'] ) ) {
      // Проверяем данные, если они существуют и не пустые, то записываем данные в поле
      update_post_meta( $post_id, '_product_field_type_ids',  array_map( 'absint', (array) $_POST['product_field_type'] ));
   } else {
      // Иначе удаляем созданное поле из бд
      delete_post_meta( $post_id, '_product_field_type_ids');
    }
}
/***************************/
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'art_get_text_field_before_show_atts_on_product_page', 40 );
function art_get_text_field_before_show_atts_on_product_page() {
global $post, $product;
  $text_field     = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_text_field', true );
  $textarea_field = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_textarea', true );

  if ( $text_field ) { ?>
    <div class="text_field">
      <strong>Поле1: </strong>
      <?php echo $text_field; ?>
    </div>
  <?php }

  if ( $textarea_field ) { ?>
    <div class="textarea_field">
      <strong>Поле2: </strong>
      <?php echo $textarea_field; ?>
    </div>
    <?php
  }
}
```

Comment: Так у вас стоит проверка на апдейт поля, если оно не пустое, уберите ее, поле должно сохраняться при любом раскладе (if(!empty($woocommerce_textarea)) и if(!empty($woocommerce_textarea)))

Comment: Спасибо) работает!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'art_woo_add_custom_fields' );
function art_woo_add_custom_fields() {
   global $product, $post;
   echo '<div class="options_group">';// Группировка полей
   // текстовое поле
   woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
      'id'                => '_text_field',
      'label'             => __( 'Текстовое поле', 'woocommerce' ),
      'placeholder'       => 'Текстовое поле',
   ) );
   // Тектовая область
   woocommerce_wp_textarea_input( array(
      'id'            => '_textarea', // Идентификатор поля
      'label'         => 'Область текста', // Заголовок поля
      'placeholder'   => 'Ввод текста', // Надпись внутри поля
      'class'         => 'textarea-field', // Произвольный класс поля
      'wrapper_class' => 'wrap-textarea', // Класс обертки поля
      'name'          => 'textarea-field', // Имя поля
   ) );
echo '</div>';
}
/*****************/
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'art_woo_custom_fields_save', 10 );
function art_woo_custom_fields_save( $post_id ) {
// Text Field
  $woocommerce_text_field = $_POST['_text_field'];
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_text_field', esc_attr( $woocommerce_text_field ) );
// Textarea
  $woocommerce_textarea = $_POST['_textarea-field'];
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_textarea', esc_html( $woocommerce_textarea ) );
   // Сохранение произвольного поля по выбору товаров с поиском
   if (  isset( $_POST['product_field_type'] ) && !empty($_POST['product_field_type'] ) ) {
      // Проверяем данные, если они существуют и не пустые, то записываем данные в поле
      update_post_meta( $post_id, '_product_field_type_ids',  array_map( 'absint', (array) $_POST['product_field_type'] ));
   } else {
      // Иначе удаляем созданное поле из бд
      delete_post_meta( $post_id, '_product_field_type_ids');
    }
}
/***************************/
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'art_get_text_field_before_show_atts_on_product_page', 40 );
function art_get_text_field_before_show_atts_on_product_page() {
global $post, $product;
  $text_field     = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_text_field', true );
  $textarea_field = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_textarea', true );

  if ( $text_field ) { ?>
    <div class="text_field">
      <strong>Поле1: </strong>
      <?php echo $text_field; ?>
    </div>
  <?php }

  if ( $textarea_field ) { ?>
    <div class="textarea_field">
      <strong>Поле2: </strong>
      <?php echo $textarea_field; ?>
    </div>
    <?php
  }
}
```